# Ограничение одновременного входа c 1 аккаунта

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть приложение на Windows Form, и форма авторизации. Необходимо ограничить пользователю вход с 1 аккаунта на разных ПК. Как это можно реализовать кроме записи в БД о состоянии и скрипта с проверкой пользователя?

Логин и пароль пользователя проверяется на сервере в БД при авторизации

Comment: Проверять надо где то на стороне - сервер.

Comment: Если у вас только winforms на клиентах и база данных на всех, то только запись в бд и код проверки этой записи на клиентах

Answer (score 2):

Никак.

Однозначно сказать залогинен пользователь или нет, может только ресурс (сервер / БД) на который он заходит.